# Swiper.js vertical silder

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

Help me please. I am developing a website that consists of 4 blocks. The "swiper" block has a vertical slider from swiper.js. I can't solve 2 problems. First, the slider should only start switching when it is fully displayed on the user's screen. And secondly, the user must necessarily switch all the slides of the slider, and only then be able to scroll the site to the "projects" block. Please help, how can this be done? The code snippet is attached below.

```
    <header class="header">
    <!-- some code here... -->
</header>
<main>
    <div class="about" id="about">
        <div class="about__text-one">We are a UAE-based EPC company proved itself remarkably effective in
            engineering,
            procurement and construction that
            supports the Oil&Gas, Energy and Chemistry industries in the Middle East and Central Asia.</div>
        <img class="about__img" src="./img/about__img.svg" alt="Map" width="800px" height="">
        <div class="about__text-two">Since establishment in 2014, FUTURIS has gained trust and has been
            registered
            by the leading Oil&Gas Companies operating
            in Central Asia and strives to contribute to the successes of the Clients' projects.</div>
    </div>
    <div style="--swiper-pagination-color: #000; --swiper-pagination-left: 150px; --swiper-pagination-bullet-size: 15px;"
        class="swiper" id="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <h2 class="fieldsOfOperation__title">Fields of Operation</h2>
                <div class="fieldOfOperation__texts">
                    <span class="fieldOfOperation__text">Oil & Gas</span>
                    <span class="fieldOfOperation__text">Chemistry</span>
                    <span class="fieldOfOperation__text">Energy</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <h2 class="expertise__title">Expertise</h2>
                <div class="expertise__texts">
                    <span class="expertise__text">Drilling Equipment</span>
                    <span class="expertise__text">Instrumentation & Electrical</span>
                    <span class="expertise__text">Valves & Pumps</span>
                    <span class="expertise__text">Mechanical Equipment & Rotating Machinery</span>
                    <span class="expertise__text">Process Equipment</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <h2 class="services__title">Services</h2>
                <div class="services__texts">
                    <span class="services__text">Automation & Control</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Commissioning & Decommissioning</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Welding</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Isolation</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Operational Assurance</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Destructive Testing</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Hydrotesting</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Intelligent Pigging</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Pipeline Equipment Maintenance</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Flow Assurance</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Construction</span>
                    <span class="services__text">Wiring</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section class="projects">
        <!-- some code here... -->
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Please put a [mre] in your question. The code you've provided so far isn't enough to reproduce your issue. You can use a Stack Snippet if that will work, or else plain code in your question _and_ a link to something like a CodePen, StackBlitz, etc.

Comment: Something like this (https://codepen.io/Juyeon/pen/povVLBE), but in first section, I have a vertical slider, not horizontal.